# Crystal report Logon failed.incorrect logon parameter while generating reports on local machine

Tags: crystal-reports

I have developed asp.net web application.I have given connection to crystal report and passing one parameter from code behind but it gets only generated when I entered parameter value same like as main preview..I want to pass parameter value through code..secondly it gives logon failed..incorrect logon parameter error while generating report in local machine itself...please help I wasted 3 days almost but not getting the solution

```
ReportDocument crstat = new ReportDocument();
crstat.Load(Server.MapPath("~/WeeklyReport_publish.rpt"));

ConnectionInfo MyConnectionInfo = new ConnectionInfo();
MyConnectionInfo.ServerName = "localhost";
MyConnectionInfo.DatabaseName = "ipro2_Process";
MyConnectionInfo.UserID = "postgres";
MyConnectionInfo.Password = "mumbai@123";

SetDBLogonForReport(MyConnectionInfo, crstat);
crstat.Refresh();


string functionID = "";

functionID = "758";

crstat.SetParameterValue(0, Convert.ToInt32(functionID));

CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = crstat;

ExportFormatType formatType = ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat;
crstat.ExportToHttpResponse(formatType, Response, true, "Weekly.pdf");
Response.End();
crstat.Close();
crstat.Dispose();
GC.Collect();
```

Comment: please provide working example and what you have tried so far.

Comment: Code have been attached.we are using postgresql database so I have used ODBC connection with connection string in Crystal Reports